# Missing array data in codeigniter php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have menu which get data from database
here is my code

```
<nav id="mysidebarmenu" class="amazonmenu">
<ul>
    <?php
    //Get Category array
    $categories = json_decode($this->db->get_where('ui_settings', array('type' => 'home_category'))->row()->value);

    foreach ($categories as $row) {
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <?php
                echo $this->crud_model->get_type_name_by_id('category', $row, 'category_name');
                ?>
            </a>
            <div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <?php
                    //Get Sub Category array
                    $subs = $this->db->get_where('sub_category', array('category' => $row['category_id']))->result_array();

                    foreach ($subs as $row1) {
                        $this->db->limit(4);
                        $this->db->order_by('product_id', 'desc');
                        $products = $this->db->get_where('product', array('sub_category' => $row1['sub_category_id'], 'status' => 'ok'))->result_array();
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-md-12"><h3 class="text-center" style="background:#EAEAEA;"><?php echo $row1['sub_category_name']; ?></h3></div>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($products as $row2) {
                            if ($this->crud_model->is_publishable($row2['product_id'])) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="menu_box">
                                        <div class="img_menu_box" style="background:url('<?php echo $this->crud_model->file_view('product', $row2['product_id'], '', '', 'no', 'src', 'multi', 'one') ?>') no-repeat center center; background-size: 100% auto;">
                                        </div>

                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->crud_model->product_link($row2['product_id']); ?>">
                                            <?php echo $row2['title']; ?>
                                        </a>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <?php
    }
    ?>


</ul>
```

**here are results i am getting**

> print_r($categories);
>   result = Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 31 )
>   print_r($subs);
>   1- result for Array [0] => 5 = ( [0] => Array ( [sub_category_id] => 18 [sub_category_name] => A [category] => 5 ) [1]
>   => Array ( [sub_category_id] => 19 [sub_category_name] => B [category] => 5 ))
>   2- result for Array [1] => 31 = Array ( )

the problem is in second array result coming empty

```
 1-   **category table & data**
        category_id | category_name
            5              cat1
           31              cat2

2-   **Sub category table & data**
    sub_category_id | sub_category_name | category
          1              C                 31
          2              D                 31
          18             A                  5
          19             B                  5
3- ui_settings table & data
ui_settings_id  |     type      |         value
       10         home_category    ["5","31"]
```

> **Expected Results** 
>  Array [1] => 31 = ( [0] => Array ( [sub_category_id]
>   => 1 [sub_category_name] => C [category] => 31 ) [1] => Array ( [sub_category_id] => 2[sub_category_name] => D [category] => 31 ))

Comment: Something in your SQL or db isn't right but it's hard to tell the exact cause as we don't have any information on the database or related functions.

Comment: @Alex please check i have added whole database structure & data it's not database problem database has data

Comment: If you are sure it's not a DB problem the functions must be the cause. Unfortunately we don't have them and even if we did that's alot of non replicable code to sift through as we don't have the same db and environment. I suggest narrowing down the issue so it's manageable and inline with stacks minimal and verifiable guidelines.

Comment: i am sure something went wrong in this piece of code, <?php
                    //Get Sub Category array
                    $subs = $this->db->get_where('sub_category', array('category' => $row['category_id']))->result_array();

                    foreach ($subs as $row1) {
                        $this->db->limit(4);
                        $this->db->order_by('product_id', 'desc');
                        $products = $this->db->get_where('product', array('sub_category' => $row1['sub_category_id'], 'status' => 'ok'))->result_array();
                        ?>

Comment: Perhaps, but again, barring any typographical or syntatical errors I can't speculate as to what the issue might be. I can say that the code doesn't have any red flags. Maybe check if the status is ok. Otherwise, make a test case and narrow down the problem to the offending db cat value of 31

Comment: @Alex, this is what i don't know yet because i am learning, if you can tell me what i need to print inside print_r($?); than i can give you results, i think this is only way stack-overflow offering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167243/discussion-between-jamez-roz-and-alex).

Answer (score 1):

First check the table ->sub_category if there are any records for  category = 31

Comment: it has please check i edit question and added all databases structure & their data

Comment: $categories = json_decode($this->db->get_where('ui_settings', array('type' => 'home_category'))->row()->value);

Comment: $categories = json_decode($this->db->get_where('ui_settings', array('type' => 'home_category'))->row()->value).
if you use $query->row() in this scenario it will return the first record only in the result as  Class Object   
you can  use $query->row_array() and $query->result_array() to get result as array instead of Class Object.

Comment: problem is in this section <?php
       //Get Sub Category array
                                $subs = $this->db->get_where('sub_category',array('category'=>$row['category_id']))->result_array();
                                foreach($subs as $row1){
                                    $this->db->limit(4);
                                    $this->db->order_by('product_id','desc');
                                    $products = $this->db->get_where('product',array('sub_category'=>$row1['sub_category_id'],'status' =>'ok'))->result_array();
                            ?>

Comment: print_r($subs);
1- result for Array [0] => 5 = ( [0] => Array ( [sub_category_id] => 18 [sub_category_name] => A [category] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [sub_category_id] => 19 [sub_category_name] => B [category] => 5 ))
2- result for Array [1] => 31 = Array ( )

Comment: as you can see Array [1] => 31 = Array ( ) is empty, please ignore $categories query that is ok problem in $sub query

Comment: use this ->print($this->db->last_query()); 
to find out what the  query was and run the same qurey in db to find out wat went wrong

Comment: it's really helpful print($this->db->last_query()); finally i found real problem the problem is here SELECT * FROM `sub_category` WHERE `category` = '3'Array ( ) query not factching data which id is more than 1 digit, for example 5 id data is showing 31 becoming 3 it's really strange, please tell me how to can i fix it, we're so close to success

Comment: i also placed  print($this->db->last_query()); after $categories it's correct SELECT * FROM `ui_settings` WHERE `type` = 'home_category'Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 31 ) but problem in here $subs